# Ignore double \newline on page break

Tags: line-breaking, page-breaking, paragraphs

When I want two paragraphs of text to be separated by an empty line in between, I use:

```
\newline
\newline
```

However, I would like that extra empty line to be ignored if it happens that the page breaks right where it would be inserted - such that there is no empty line starting a new page.

I am new to Latex, but it seems to me that people don't want to leave empty lines between paragraphs, but just have the next one indented as is Latex default.

Is there a natural implementation for the 'wide paragraph break' such that Tex behaves as I want it to on pagebreaks?

I read about parskip, but I don't want this behavior for every new paragraph, just for some.

Comment: There are macros `\smallskip`, `\medskip`, and `\bigskip`, in addition to the `\parskip` feature (the latter will apply at all paragraph breaks).

Comment: Will those skip commands be ignored at a pagebreak?

Comment: Yes. those commands are all skipped at a pagebreak

Comment: `\newline\newline` is simply bad input  neither one ends the current paragraph, it just forces a blank line (and a warning about  bad output) in teh current paragraph.

Comment: I don't think to have ever used `\newline` in one of my documents, except in a handful of very special situations. Surely not to leave vertical space. Get rid of `\newline` in your documents, you'll be happier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LaTeX offers certain sizes of vertical skips given by `\smallskip`, `\medskip`, and `\bigskip`. These can be invoked for a local change in the vertical spacing, unlike `\parskip<length>`, which will apply to all subsequent paragraph breaks.

If these pre-packaged sizes are not suitable for your needs, you can use `\vspace{<length>}` instead.  As long as the `*` version of `\vspace` is avoided, the space will not be applied at a page break.

You will see that `\bigskip` has no effect at the top of page 2.  The same comment is true of the other vertical skips.

```
\documentclass[letter]{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
text

text

\smallskip 
text

\medskip
text

\bigskip
text

\vspace{6.4in}
some other text on a new line

\bigskip
x
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

One should keep in mind that `\newline` operates within a paragraph, whereas these skips operate between paragraphs.  In this sense, the use of `\noindent` may also be useful with the proposed technique, depending on the OP's application.

Comment: the behaviour of all these skips, and of `\vspace` is easier to understand if you add them in vertical mode, so have a blank line before, not after. Adding vertical skips in hmode as here works but is a much more convoluted code path involving vadjust nodes.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for clarifying that nuance, of which I had been unaware.

Comment: to see the difference add some following text so `xxx\bigskip yyy` compared to `\zzz[blank line]\bigskip yyy`  note the skip gets added _somewhere_ but not where you place the command in the source in the first case.

Answer (score 2):

vertical space is always dropped at a page break, `\newline\newline` is the same as

```
\newline 
please ignore this text
\newline
```

that is, it does not end the paragraph or add vertical space, it simply extends the current paragraph by a spurious empty line (and latex will warn about underful hbox).
As the white area is a (empty) line of text not a vertical space it is preserved at the top of a page just as any other line is preserved.

If you want a style that marks paragraphs by no indentation and vertical space then that can be set by the docuemnt class, or for the standard document classes which do not have that option use

```
\usepackage{parskip}
```

If you only want vertical space for some paragraphs then usually that is implied by whatever structural markup you ate using so for example `\begin{quote}...\end{quote}` will add vertical space,  as will markup for theorems etc.

If you *really* want a one-off space then end the paragraph with a blank line as usual and then add extra space with `\vspace` that will be dropped at a page break (the variant `\vspace*` produces a space that is not dropped.)

```
para...

\vspace{10pt}
new para
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\nl}{\newline\vspace{1cm}}
\begin{document}
Then we map spin operators to spinless fermionic creation and annihilation operator by Jordan–Wigner transformation.
\nl
The Hamiltonian obtained is closely related to Kitaev's one-dimensional p-wave superconductor, a model for a topological superconductor in one dimension.
```

And use `\nl` where you were using `\newline`.

Enter any size in place of `1cm` like `12pt`.

Use `\newcommand{\nl}{\newline\vspace{1cm}\par}` if you want indentation.

Comment: and those extra 12pt will be ignored on a page break?

Comment: Yes, that extra 12pt will be ignored on a page break.

Comment: No the `\newline` is wrong.